# how to read a file of combination of numbers and save saving each combination into a new file name?

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a combination file with certain combination numbers like:

(133, 134), (133, 100), (133, 438), (133, 414), (133, 35), (133, 130), (133, 143), (133, 383), (134, 100), (134, 438), (134, 414), (134, 35), (134, 130), (134, 143), (134, 383), (100, 438), (100, 414), (100, 35), (100, 130), (100, 143), (100, 383), (438, 414), (438, 35), (438, 130), (438, 143), (438, 383), (414, 35), (414, 130), (414, 143), (414, 383), (35, 130), (35, 143), (35, 383), (130, 143), (130, 383), (143, 383)

I want to save each combination into a new file name with Addition of string "A" after each number.

I have already tried with reading character by character but it's not working.

```
import functools

with open ("combi2.txt", "r+") as f:
    f_read_ch=functools.partial(f.read,3)
    for ch in iter (f_read_ch,''):
        print(repr(ch))
```

Combi_1.txt
133 A \n
134 A

Combi_2.txt
133 A \n
100 A

Combi_3.txt
133 A \n
134 A

Comment: each combination should be in separate file like: (100,35) in file Combi_1_100_35.txt?

Comment: yes, and the combination should be added with string  "A " after numbers. like:    100 A \n 35 A

Comment: see below example of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import re

# collect data
raw_data = []
with open('combi2.txt', 'r') as file:
     data = file.readlines()
     raw_data.append(data[0])

# find numbers sets in text
numbers_set = re.findall('(\d+,\s\d+)', raw_data[0])

# create files
count = 0
for item in numbers_set:
    element = item.split(', ')
    file = open('Combi_' + str(count) + '.txt', 'w')
    file.write(element[0] + ' A ' + element[1] + ' A')
    count += 1
```

Output example:

```
Combi_0.txt with 133 A 134 A inside
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts one part you solved it, one part you misunderstood. The Combination inside file should be written wtih 35 A  130 A  without ( ),  not the file name. Sorry for bothering you. :(

Comment: @Ron Ledger and the file names simply Combi_1.txt , Combi_2.txt and so on ?

Comment: Just a question, what's the point of calling `readlines` for a single line file, storing that list in a variable when your next step is get the first element of that list (of a single element) to store it in another one? Where, finally, you are going to take just the first element again. Why you didn't do something like `text = file.read()`and then use `text`on your `findall`function directly?

Comment: @RonLedger yep i don't change that , at first i assumed that file will contains multiple rows